# How to refresh cell values in an excel workbook automatically?

Tags: excel

I have an excel workbook that contains 3 worksheets.

Worksheet 1 contains the input cell on cell A1 (i.e. a drop down list).
Worksheet 2's cell B2 reference the information of cell A1 of worksheet 1.
Worksheet 3's cell B3 reference the information of cell A1 of worksheet 1 too.

However, when I change the value of cell A1 of worksheet 1, it seems like the referenced values don't change automatically - which seem strange.

Is there any method I could use to evoke an update automatically whenever cell A1 change?

Comment: Sounds like calculation is set to manual.  See @Pirion's suggestion below.

Answer (score 5):

> On the Tools menu, click Options, and then click the Calculation tab.
>
> To recalculate all dependent formulas—except data tables—every time
>   you make a change to a value, formula, or name, click Automatic except
>   tables.

Source:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/change-when-and-how-formulas-are-recalculated-HP005199227.aspx